# "Error establishing a database connection" in local WordPress environment after Yosemite upgrade

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, localhost

Upgrading to Yosemite changed my local development Apache/PHP/MySQL environment and thus broke my local WordPress sites. I was able to get things in order by tweaking my local Apache config back to what it was using the httpd.conf~previous file as a reference.

Once I got Apache working as expected, I started getting the "Error establishing a database connection" error though nothing had changed in my wp-config.php file.

I had read a solution about capitalizing the "localhost" DB_HOST constant to "Localhost" in wp-config, but that didn't work.

It's a homebrew install of MySQL and I can access the "localhost" db server with command line and SequelPro app.

Comment: You can access the server...but can you access the database? Is the correct user created and `GRANT`ed permissions on this database?

Comment: Yeah I can access the database too - privileges are intact from when the environment was working.

Answer (score 6):

I changed the DB_HOST to the internal IP "127.0.0.1" and that fixed it.

Comment: Wow - just ran around in circles for an hour trying to figure this out ... why is this?

Comment: i set in wp-config.php Like...=>define('DB_NAME', 'tg');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');==> But, Still not connect with MySQLServer...

Answer (score 0):

OSX Yosemite (and maybe other newer versions of OSX as well) looks in the wrong location for the mysql.sock file, which is why upgrading to Yosemite broke your local sites. Creating a symlink to the correct location will solve the problem:

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
sudo chmod 755 /var/mysql
sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

The reason the missing symlink is a problem for WordPress specifically is because in your wp-config.php file, `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');` will not work. An alternative workaround is to change this value in your wp-config file to `define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');`.